# I can't see the input value in the input in html controller

Tags: c#, .net, post, model-view-controller, html.beginform

The model of my html page is in the form of a list. I want to enter the exam grade here, but when I entered the exam grade, my data does not go to my actionResult type function. In fact, when I write an integer value to the input, it does not save its value. The database also lists the values I have written manually, but still does not bring the data to the function.

my html code:

```
@model IEnumerable<OnlineBasvuru.Entity.ViewModel.ExamViewModal>

@{
    Layout = null;
}
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Exam", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr> 
                    <th>
                        StudentId
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Note
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.ToList())
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.Label(item.StudentId.Value.ToString())
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Note)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }

            </tbody>

        </table>
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    }
</div>
```

my controller code:

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Save(ICollection<ExamViewModal> nwModal) // Normally nwModal should be listed as a list of the model and the data should be in
            {

            foreach (ExamViewModal modal in nwModal)
            {
                EXAM exam = examService.Get(modal.Id);
                exam.NOTE = modal.Note;
                examService.Save(exam );
            }

            return RedirectToAction("ExamList", "Exam");
        }
```

Please show me a way I do not know how to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `for` loop instead of a `foreach`. This will then set the name property using indexes rather than spitting out the same name for each item in the loop.

For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++) {
   Html.EditorFor(m => Model[i].Note)
}
```

Comment: I was about to suggest the same first. Can you please explain why it works with `for` and not with `foreach`? Can you point me to a good explanation somewhere?

Comment: Mainly know this from experience in dealing with similar situations. Don't know of an online resource for this. If you look at the HTML output from the foreach you will see it add name="item.Note" to each textbox. With the for loop it adds name="[0].Note", name="[1].Note" so you have unique identifiers. The form needs to identify all elements and if they have the same name/id then it can't do that.

Comment: I've experienced the same as well. So my search still continues as to why `for` gives a different output than `foreach`. Why can't dotnet framework do this itself! Will update here if I find something.